# Get specific service that many class implemented that service without instantiate other classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I have below example:

```
public interface IPerson
{
     string Name {get;}
}
```

and 2 classes Implement this interface as below:

```
public class John : IPerson
{
         string Name {get;} = "John";
}

public class Anna : IPerson
{
         string Name {get;} = "Anna";
}
```

When using Service provider i use below method

```
serviceProvider.GetServices<IPerson>().SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name== "John");
```

As I know all tow class instantiated  and above method returns a class that its name is "John".
Actually I have many of these classes and its not a good idea to do this in this way. Is it a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's at stake here.

Comment: In order to check the name you will require the instance, which means initializing all

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You are using the service locator which is usually an anti-pattern. However since you are using Autofac, you should consider using named/keyed services.